# Chrome extension onMessage.addListener in service worker getting called twice when 2+ extension tabs open

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-chrome-extension

When I have a 2 or more of my extension tabs open chrome.runtime.sendMessage and chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener runs twice. When I have on tab it works fine. How do i fix this and what is causing it.

**Main.tsx**

```
 const generate = async (type: dalleReqTypes): Promise<void> => {
    try {
      await chrome.runtime
        .sendMessage({
          action: "dalle-fetch",
          type: type,
          request: {
            n: numToGen,
            prompt: prompt,
            image: selectedImg,
          },
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

**Service_worker.ts**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (message.action === "dalle-fetch") {
    const dalleReq = message.request as DalleRequest;
        getDalleGenerations(dalleReq)
          .then(() => {
            sendResponse({ result: "success" });
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            sendResponse({ result: "error", dalleReq: error.toString() });
          });
});
```

**Manifest.json**

```
{
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "App",
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html",
    "default_title": "App",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "images/camera.png",
      "48": "images/camera.png",
      "128": "images/camera.png"
    }
  },
  "background": { "service_worker": "service_worker.js", "type": "module" },
  "minimum_chrome_version": "92",
  "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>",],
  "permissions": ["contextMenus", "desktopCapture", "storage", "activeTab"],
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/camera.png",
    "48": "images/camera.png",
    "128": "images/camera.png"
  }
}
```

**App.tsx**

```
function App() {
  return (
    <HashRouter>
      <Suspense fallback={<div></div>}>
        <Routes>
          <Route index path="/" element={<Main isPopup={true} />} />
          <Route path="/browser" element={<Main isPopup={false} />} />
          <Route path="/cropper" element={<Cropper />} />
          <Route path="/settings" element={<Settings />} />
        </Routes>
      </Suspense>
    </HashRouter>
  );
}
```

I have tried to store a boolean in chrome.storage.local to check if another request is currently in flight but this did not work. I have also tried moving code logic from service worker but I want requests to trigger in the background after popup has closed, so i think I need it in service worker to maintain this feature.

Comment: Is this **exactly** the same code you have on your computer, or did you remove something before pasting it into Stackoverflow?

Comment: i removed some of it to make it more concise and readable.

Comment: 1) How did you determine it runs twice? 2) Do you import from Service_worker.ts anywhere in your tab scripts? 3) Do you have chrome.runtime.onMessage anywhere in your tab scripts or action popup scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. The following is the proper way to send messages to service worker.

navigator.serviceWorker.controller?.postMessage({
action: "dalle-fetch",
type: type,
});